# How to have a page with long text that is wrapped automatically based on the phone screen

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am trying to make a book application. I am stucked with the text that can show long string. Basically, I tried to use UI Label, but it is only showing one line and the remaining of the text is cut.

Any idea what kind of UI that I should use to make a book? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UITextView for such purpose check

```
UITextView *aboutStable = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[aboutStable setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
[aboutStable setText:@"Write your long text here............iphonemaclover is great"];
[aboutStable setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[aboutStable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[aboutStable setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[aboutStable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 302, 320, 79)];
[self addSubview:aboutStable];
```

And make it not editable so set

`[aboutStable setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` 
should do it

and if you need scrolling:

```
aboutStable.editable = NO;
```

or if you text is still more,then you can set scrollview in it too...

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 195, 280, 10)];
textView.text = @"your long text here";
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hevlatica" size:14];
[self.scrollView addSubview:textView];//add scrollview using Xib and set property of it.
CGRect descriptionFrame = textView.frame;
descriptionFrame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame = descriptionFrame;
```

or you can check more detail here in this [sample code](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uitextview_uitextviewdelegate_2/)

EDIT FOR DIFFERENT RETINA DISPLAY

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f)
   {
    //condition for iphone 5 screen
   }
else
{
 //condition for retina display 3.5
}
```

Comment: ok, I found that [aboutStable setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)]; is the perfect rectangle for the textview. But I just realize one more thing, what if the users using retina display or another phone that has different size. How to handle multiple size of iphone in this case.

Comment: check the edit part in above answer dont forget to upvote if it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Set the [numberOfLines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines) for the UILabel to 0, to let it use as many lines as it needs.